# why am i getting a syntax error for the if statement below

Tags: php, arrays

```
if($gradeArray[1] == NULL ||is_nan($gradeArray[1]) || $gradeArray[2] == NULL || is_nan($gradeArray[2]) || $gradeArray[3] == NULL || is_nan($gradeArray[3]) || $gradeArray[4] == NULL || is_nan($gradeArray[4]) || $gradeArray[5] == NULL || is_nan($gradeArray[5]) || $gradeArray[6] == NULL || is_nan($gradeArray[6]) || $gradeArray[7] == NULL || is_nan($gradeArray[7]) || $gradeArray[8] == NULL || is_nan($gradeArray[8]) || $gradeArray[9] == NULL || is_nan($gradeArray[9]) || $gradeArray[0] == NULL || is_nan($gradeArray[0])){
    echo "<h2>Please enter scores in ALL textboxes.</h2>";
} else {
    //pass array into the function
    arrayFunction($gradeArray);
}
```

Comment: What language Is it?  PHP?

Comment: Whatever language this is, save us all and loop over `gradeArray[]`

Comment: @ali We can't really help if you don't give us the actual error message.

Answer (score 1):

```
$hasErrors = false;

foreach ($gradeArray as $gradeValue) {
    if (!is_numeric($gradeValue)) {
        $hasErrors = true;
    }
}

if ($hasErrors) {
    echo "<h2>Please enter scores in ALL textboxes.</h2>";
} else {
    arrayFunction($gradeArray);
}
```

Explanation: Instead of checking each value in the array individually if it is null or not a number, you can iterate over each element in the array and check if it is not numeric (`is_numeric()`), which includes the check for `null`.

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?

Comment: Added the explanation, thanks for the nudge, @MarkusWMahlberg !

Comment: @jeromegamez, thanks for the explanation, yet still, it wont display right, there is a "bad gateway" error. I am not sure what I m doing wrong

Comment: @ali A bad gateway error seems to be a different story.